# 'Link status: down' shown when run dpdk testpmd

Tags: dpdk

I am using Netronome 4000 SmartNIC. After binding a VF to dpdk driver, I try to run dpdk testpmd but it shows 'Link status: down'. I also try to bring the port up in testpmd, but it also fails.

Do I need to explicitly bring up the interface/port in some way?

```
lspci -kd 19ee: 05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Netronome Systems, Inc. Device 4000
        Subsystem: Netronome Systems, Inc. Device 4000
        Kernel driver in use: nfp
        Kernel modules: nfp 05:08.0 Ethernet controller: Netronome Systems, Inc. Device 6003
        Subsystem: Netronome Systems, Inc. Device 4000
        Kernel driver in use: igb_uio
        Kernel modules: nfp

testpmd> show port info all

********************* Infos for port 0  *********************
MAC address: 00:15:4D:00:00:00
Device name: 0000:05:08.0
Driver name: net_nfp_vf
Connect to socket: 0
memory allocation on the socket: 0
Link status: down
Link speed: 0 Mbps
Link duplex: half-duplex
MTU: 1500
Promiscuous mode: enabled
Allmulticast mode: disabled
Maximum number of MAC addresses: 1
Maximum number of MAC addresses of hash filtering: 0
VLAN offload:
  strip off, filter off, extend off, qinq strip off
Hash key size in bytes: 40
Redirection table size: 128
Supported RSS offload flow types:
  ipv4
  ipv4-tcp
  ipv4-udp
  ipv6
  ipv6-tcp
  ipv6-udp
Minimum size of RX buffer: 68
Maximum configurable length of RX packet: 9216
Maximum configurable size of LRO aggregated packet: 0
Current number of RX queues: 1
Max possible RX queues: 1
Max possible number of RXDs per queue: 32768
Min possible number of RXDs per queue: 64
RXDs number alignment: 128
Current number of TX queues: 1
Max possible TX queues: 1
Max possible number of TXDs per queue: 32768
Min possible number of TXDs per queue: 64
TXDs number alignment: 128
Max segment number per packet: 255
Max segment number per MTU/TSO: 8

testpmd> set link-up port 0
nfp_net_set_link_up(): Set link up

Set link up fail.
```

Comment: is the PF link up? as  I recollect most NIC requires PF to be up, as link status for VF is connected to PF link status register

Comment: the link status `Link status: down, Link speed: 0 Mbps, Link duplex: half-duplex` is the default setting when link is not connected or configured

Comment: how to set the link up? Do I need to set it before I bind the NIC to dpdk driver?

Comment: As per the question you posted you are using VF `binding a VF to dpdk driver`. Inorder to get the PF link up, connect the physical cable to a NIC or Switch and ensure the Link is up. Assuming the PF is managed by Kernel you can check the link state with `ethtool [PF interface name]`

Comment: are there any updates on the link status of PF as requested earlier? were you able to resolve the issue?